# Using @Value for a @CustomAnnotation in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, annotations

I've read similar questions and relative answers but didn't find one whose fit.

In the given sample:

```java
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = DescriptionValidationImpl.class)
public @interface DescriptionValidation {

    public String message() default "default"; 

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

How can i read a value from the `.properties` file and assign it to the message,
knowing that `@Value` isn't a compile-time constant?

Heard someone doing with the ExceptionHandlrController, is it possible? How?
And if i were in need of different messages for the same catched exc?

I've tried the following too even if it didn't make no sense for me:

```java
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:message.properties")
public class DescriptionProcessing {

    @Value("${description}")
    private String descriptionErrorMsg;

    public void processAnnotation(DescriptionValidation annotation) {

        String defaultDescriptionErrorMsg = annotation.message();

        if (defaultDescriptionErrorMsg.equals("default"))
            defaultDescriptionErrorMsg = descriptionErrorMsg;
    }
}
```

But kept printing the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Using a bean in a config file and calling it back from the excHandlr.

In the `@Annotation` `@interface` were in need of the placeholder of `@Value`
i.e.

```java
public String message() default "description";
```

in the given example but'll probably be something like `"error.description"` or whatever